# if $\bar{F}$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $P \in \mathbb{C}$, then $F$ reverses angle at $P$?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I want to prove that if $\bar{F}$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $P \in \mathbb{C}$, then $F$ reverses angle at $P$.

Any idea or hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Any holomorphic function preserves the angle at its regular points? What will happen in the case of critical point?? And then observe that angle of $F$ reverse the angle of the angle of $\bar{F}$.

Comment: @Anubhav, how can tell that $F$ reverse the angle of $\overline{F}$?

Comment: consider two particular vector, draw the picture and observe what is happening.